# React app extending github repo name to the end of url (local and github pages)

Tags: reactjs, github-pages, react-routing

I hope people are still using Stack overflow because I failed myself first and then ChatGPT failed me.

My problem is that I am trying to deploy this React app of mine to github pages and something weird is happening.

When I deploy the app, the url is correct but I get a 404 error.

When I run it locally, it runs the app on http://localhost:3000/my-portfolio

my-portfolio is the github repo name and it shouldn't be there.

I don't understand how my-portfolio is added to the end of the url.

This is my routing:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <RootElement />,
    errorElement: <Error />,
    children: [
      { index: true, element: <Home /> },
      { path: "about-me", element: <About /> },
      { path: "work-history", element: <WorkHistory /> },
      { path: "projects", element: <Projects /> },
      { path: "skills", element: <Skills /> },
      { path: "blog", element: <Blog /> },
      { path: "contact", element: <Contact /> },
    ],
  },
]);

function App() {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}

export default App;
```

And I have added my github repo link as the homepage in package.json:

```
  "homepage": "https://mustafa-haidari.github.io/my-portfolio",
```

I couldn't figure out what the problem is. I searched through the whole app for ***my-portfolio*** but I couldn't figure out the problem.

I would really appreciate if someone guide me towards the right direction here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me after I remove "homepage": line in package.json, and run yarn install again. It runs at localhost:3000 instead of localhost:3000/repo-name